# Solid State Relay for small AC loads

Tags: arduino, relay, solid-state-relay

I need a SSR to switch AC less than 5v. It is a very small AC load and according to my multimeter, it varies between .5 and 1 V. I have looked every where but every SSR available the I've found have a minimum load requirement. The OMRON G3MB-202P for example requires a minimum of 75ACV to work. I know I could use an electromagnetic relay but I have found that those don't last to long.

So, is there a SSR with DC control and for small AC load?

If there is no SSR, would there be another alternative to control small AC loads with DC?

Also, I am using an arduino to switch the relay ON/OFF so the SSR's control voltage has to be DC.

Answer (score 2):

Look into PhotoMOS or OptoMOS.  This is an optocoupler with bidirectional MOSFETs as the pass element.  Some are rated over 1 A.  CP Clare invented this but now it is owned by IXYS.  Here are some things to look for.  Once you locate the series you can fish around for a model that fits your application

International Rectifier PVN and PVI series

Toshiba TLP222 series

IXYS LBA716